# Remove users from Firebase database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I start learn more about Firebase and i try to create a simple database.

I follow all steps from website and i successfully added members in database.

But...now, it's necessary to learn how can remove an user.

Here is my code to add and remove users:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>


  </head>
    <body>
      <button onclick="saveData()">Save Data</button>
      <button onclick="printData()">Print Data</button>
      <button onclick="printData2()">Print Data2</button>
      <button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
      <script>
        var ref = new Firebase("https://projecttest-9aee9.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog");
        var usersRef = ref.child("users");
        function saveData(){
        usersRef.set({
          alanisawesome: {
            date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
            full_name: "Alan Turing"
          },
          gracehop: {
            date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
            full_name: "Grace Hopper"
          }
        });
      }
      function printData(){

        usersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      });
      }
       function printData2(){

        ref.child("users/gracehop/date_of_birth").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());//"December 9, 1906"
      }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      });
      }


      function remove(){
                  ref.removeUser({
                    alanisawesome: {
                    date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
                    full_name: "Grace Hopper"
                                   }

                  });
          }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where is the problem with remove users function?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `removeUser` is not defined anywhere. Second, I don't think you're using the correct `ref` in `remove()`, you should use `usersRef`.

Try using the `user.remove()` method.

From [the User API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#delete) reference:

> Deletes and signs out the user.
>
> Important: this is a security sensitive operation that requires the
>   user to have recently signed in. If this requirement isn't met, ask
>   the user to authenticate again and then call
>   firebase.User#reauthenticate.

If you want to delete the database node corresponding to a user, you could do something like this:

```
usersRef.remove()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Remove succeeded.")
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
  });
```

Comment: var ref = new Firebase("https://projecttest-9aee9.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog");
    ref.remove({
    alanisawesome: {
            date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
            full_name: "Alan Turing"
          }
              });

Comment: Maybe...something like that? Thaanks for help!

Comment: That's it! Thaank you again! Have a nice day :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help